# syntax error near unexpected token `(' with quoted arguments with gdbserver

Tags: command-line, gdbserver

My program accepts quoted arguments which contain brackets inside. If I pass these arguments to a gdbserver as if I run it standalone, I get an error

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Example of standalone run:

```
myprogram 12 3 "sin(x)"
```

Example of gdbserver run:

```
gdbserver :2345 myprogram 12 3 "sin(x)"
```

How to overcome?

Comment: have you tried escaping them like so? `"sin\(x\)"`

Comment: Yes, but this causes my program not to understand parameters, since it eats quotes

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and this is what helped to me:

```
gdbserver :2345 myprogram 12 3 "'sin(x)'"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [a bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=25893) in gdbserver, fixed in version 10.1. Try a newer version.

```bash
gdbserver --version  # GNU gdbserver (Ubuntu 9.2-0ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.2
gdbserver :2345 -- ./myprogram 12 3 "sin(x)"
# /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
# /bin/bash: -c: line 0: `exec -- ./myprogram 12 3 sin(x)'
# During startup program exited with code 1.
# Exiting

./gdbserver12 --version  # GNU gdbserver (GDB) 12.1
./gdbserver12 :2345 -- ./myprogram 12 3 "sin(x)"
gdb -q -ex 'target remote tcp::2345' -ex 'b main' -ex 'c' -ex 'n' -ex 'p (*argv)@argc'
# $4 = {0x7fffffffdabe "./myprogram", 0x7fffffffdaca "12", 0x7fffffffdacd "3", 0x7fffffffdacf "sin(x)"}
```